# How to make a differential measurement using two single-ended circuits that are high-z isolated?

Tags: circuit-design, signal, signal-processing

Consider this system: There is an AC source that is differential w.r.t to ground. To measure this signal, I setup a diff-buffer and then feed the output to an ADC which measures the differential signal w.r.t. the same ground.
[image]

I need to make the same differential measurement now. However, I have two circuits that can only access one terminal and therefore, make only single ended measurements and their systems are referred to the same ground via a high impedance connection. Is it possible to design a front end to do so?

[image]

Comment: What is your dynamic range on both systems? What are your  power rails?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: Is there no way to at least connect the grounds of the two ADC subsystems to each other?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a differential probe? Or an isolated probe? Either would augment "single ended measurement" with two wires with which you could make a differential measurement similar to your diagram above with respect to the individual ground of each single-ended sub-circuit and more or less independently of the common ground.

Comment: @laptop2d +/- 3V, supplies exceed that

Comment: @jsotola No its not

Comment: @ThePhoton that would have been easy, unfortunately, not

Comment: @DKNguyen Umm, not sure I understand. Are you saying I should make differential measurements of each (instead of single ended ones)?

Comment: @user1155386 Yes because what your proposed approach doesn't make much sense to me. How is the single-ended ADC system supposed to get any accurate reading with respect to the common ground if it cannot reference the common ground?

Answer (score 0):

Some scopes have a vertical-measurement setting of A-B. Not all scopes, but some.

This likely will not provide the best common-mode rejection possible.

Special probes, or special plugins, can be your friend.

Comment: Any example of such special probes?

Comment: google Agilent differential probes

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have two circuits that can only access one terminal and
>   therefore, make only single ended measurements and their systems are
>   referred to the same ground via a high impedance connection. Is it
>   possible to design a front end to do so?

You probably have a DAQ or something like it, you can take measurements and subtract them with single ended measurements. The result will be much more noisy and much less accurate than then the differential measurement because of the way the measuring currents flow through both systems.

With the differential setup, the amplifier does the subtraction, noise common to both terminals is subtracted. Ground currents are not as much of an issue because they are common to the differential measurement.

With the two single ended measurement, noise that is common to both terminals is not subtracted, and any noise currents will cause the ground of the single ended measurement to bounce because of the large isolating resistances involved. This means the single ended measurements will be more noisy and the noise will be harder to subtract out, because the single ended systems have slightly different gains and offsets.

So you can make single ended measurements like that and the sacrifice of accuracy. I have done so when I didn't have a way to make the measurement differenitally, then I promptly went asked for a differential probe to be put on the budget. It all depends on how much you can tolerate the noise and error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reject a CM noise each measurement probe or system must used a common reference over the spectrum of the desired signal.  Otherwise, the common mode signal that is “not common” appears in the differential output.

It is assumed that noise outside your signal spectrum can be filtered out before being/after being measured to prevent saturation.

The standard test for such a A-B measurement system is to replace the differential source impedance with a resistor and expect a flat line output down x dB below your minimum worst case signal to noise ratio, SNR.

This is easily done with INA instrument amplifiers with dual wire shield or STP cable and to get well below 10uV noise levels using active guarding of the signals.

If you are unable to connect your signal grounds together, e.g. the grid many km away, then filtering of unwanted CM noise is essential to match the spectrum of your signals.

Active guarding, controlled impedance ( AC coupled into 50 Ohms) and triple shielding are methods to reduce stray noise .

Comment: Any questions here?